# take something for granted as something vs. take something for granted

Tags: usage

Is it poor style to say the following?

> A lot of things we take for granted as trash, such as newspapers, magazines, old computers and cellphones, can actually be recycled in one way or another.

Aren't we supposed to say the following?

> We take it for granted that a lot of things are trash, such as newspapers, magazines, old computers and cellphones, but actually they can be recycled in one way or another.

In authoritative dictionaries (both print and online), I can only find "take something for granted" or "take it for granted that" (if the object is too long).

Comment: Why are you asking about this sentence? Did you find it in a publication somewhere? The place you found this sentence will tell us what kind of style is appropriate for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct - the first example is grammatically incorrect. But regardless of the grammar, I don't find "take for granted" to be a suitable phrase in this context at all. It is not just a substitute for the word 'assume'.

The saying to 'take something for granted' has a few different applications, but the primary meaning is to assume that something is a 'given', perhaps to assume that something will *always* be there without any thought or effort. I think this quote is implying is *to not give something the proper thought*. But what your quote seems to be saying is that people think certain things *are* trash. What you are actually trying to say is that they haven't considered the alternative, which is recycling.

I would have said:

> A lot of things we **consider to be** trash, such as newspapers, magazines, old computers and cellphones, can actually be recycled in one way or another.

Comment: I disagree: what exactly do you think is grammatically incorrect about the first sentence?  We take these things for granted.  In what way do we take them for granted?  *As trash.*   I don't think it's the best written sentence ever, but I don't see anything actually incorrect about it.

Comment: @stangdon That's really not how "taken for granted" is used and it does not fit this context. Literally, it means that something is a "given". For example, we might take for granted running water in our homes, without giving much thought to how it gets there, or that some people don't have it. It wouldn't mean that the water isn't water, or that we haven't thought of alternative ways of getting water. In the OP's example, nobody is being "given" anything. There is no process being overlooked. The people who consider things "trash" are physically doing the throwing away themselves.

Comment: @Astralbee This is a literal, word-for-word translation of a Chinese sentence. It's interesting that there is nothing wrong with the Chinese.

Comment: @stangdon You're right to some extent. The following are two sentences from  Corpus of Contemporary American English: 1. Most prospective parents take the process of procreation for granted as natural and practically automatic. 2. Modern societies have tended to take science for granted as a way of knowing, ordering and controlling the world.  It seems that some native speakers do use the phrase in this way, though I'm baffled by such a usage.

Comment: @user443543 Your two examples don't disagree with my point, they support it. Nature, and science, are two things that people DO take for granted. They know they exist, but they know they work on their behalf, and they don't need to know much about either of those things for them to do so. Your example isn't like these. 'Trash' isn't something we take for granted.

Comment: @Astralbee Do they also support your point that the sentence is grammatically incorrect?

Comment: @user443543 Only your first is wrong. Either something is taken for granted, or it is not. We don't take something for granted 'as' something. It doesn't make sense, it isn't idiomatic. I didn't really dwell on that matter because the fact it doesnt fit the context anyway makes that moot.

Comment: @Astralbee I totally agree with you that it isn't idiomatic, but I cannot understand why the two examples are correct.  Most prospective parents take the process of procreation for granted\the process of procreation is natural and practically automatic.  Am I not supposed to understand it in this way?